# PrettyPhoto inline Content div hide show

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, prettyphoto

I have a problem with PrettyPhoto
in inline content there is two div and one button.I want that when I clickedn button divisionImage will hide and divisionVideo will show. here is a codes inline content and div hide show function not working

```
<div id="inline-content" class="hide" style="text-align: center;">
     <input id="btn1" type="button" name="btnCzmVideo" value="Çözüm Videosu"
      onclick="VideoGoster()" />
     <div id="divisionImage" style="text-align: center;">
     <img id="imgCozumIcerigi" src="#" />                 
     </div>
     <div id="divisionVideo" style="display: none;">
     </div>
</div>
function VideoGoster() {    
    $("#divisionImage").css('visibility', 'hidden');
    $('#divVideo').show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved 
actually divs hided and showed but u cant see
in prettyphoto modal when press right arrrow  PrettyPhoto Content refreshed and your divs is hided and showed what you wanted.
send right arrow key or left arrow key to page programatically and problem was solved